# Only one undefined is printed while using console.log twice in two functions

Tags: javascript

I have following piece of code:

```
function a()
{
    x = 2;
    console.log(x);
}

function b()
{
    x = 4;
    console.log(x);
}

a();
b();
```

What am I expecting as output is:

```
2
undefined
4
undefined
```

but the output I got is:

```
2
4
undefined
```

where is one of the undefined?
Screenshot from chrome console:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your code works fine and doesn't prints any `undefined`

Comment: I am testing it in chrome console. console.log returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In consoles like the one in Chrome, when a code or a code block is executed, it is treated as a single function that must return something. When you run this block:

```
a()
b()
```

console is treating it like:

```
(function() {
  a()
  b()
})()
```

And of course it is not returning anything.

If you call those functions individually, you will see 2 `undefined`s.

HTH

PS: `undefined`s sounds funny :)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's Console intended to return the last function of your code block. But since there was nothing to return, it outputs undefined.

Here's some proof.

```
function a()
{
    x = 2;
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}

function b()
{
    x = 4;
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}

a();
b();
```

Comment: Updated it to actually answer your question.